# Qt: QSslCertificate::fromPath doesn't find my file, but QFileInfo finds it

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, certificate

I have the problem that in the code below, "QSslCertificate::fromPath" doesn't find the file I specified, but when I check it with the fileExists-function below, it tells me that the file exists after all. This problem only occurs when I try to run my application on a PC different from my development PC. I develop on Windows 10 64 Bit, the test PC is Windows 7 64 Bit. I use QT 5.4.0. What am I doing wrong?

```
void MyClass::init()
{

    // ... some other init code

    QLatin1String rootCApath = QLatin1String("./ssl/rootCA.crt");
    if (fileExists(rootCApath))
        log("File exists"); // This is just a log function for displaying messages in the GUI.
    else
        log("File doesn't exist");

    static QList<QSslCertificate> cert = QSslCertificate::fromPath(rootCApath);
    if(cert.size()==1)
    {
        ssl_configuration.setCaCertificates(cert);
        m_webSocket.setSslConfiguration(ssl_configuration);
    }
    else
    {
        QString s = "Server certificate not found. Size is " + QString::number(cert.size());
        log(s);
    }
}

bool MyClass::fileExists(QString path) {
    QFileInfo check_file(path);
    // check if file exists and if yes: Is it really a file and no directory?
    return check_file.exists() && check_file.isFile();
}
```

edit: And when I read the certificate into a QByteArray and pass that one on, then my connect function doesn't do anything on that Windows 7 PC, while on my Windows 10 Developer PC everything still works fine.

Also there is yet another PC which consistently gives me TLS handshake errors, no matter what I do. 3 PCs, 3 results, it's so depressing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in my case: I didn't add the OpenSSL libraries libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll to the directory where my exe resides in.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine and working on my linux system without any issue. You should check relative path or simply try to set the cert via QFileInfo :

```
QLatin1String rootCApath = QLatin1String("./ssl/rootCA.crt");
QFileInfo temp(rootCApath);
QString tempssl;
QDir dir ;//try to set dir also if this does not work dir("/home/foo/yourapppath/");  

tempssl=dir.relativeFilePath("./ssl/rootCA.crt");   
static QList<QSslCertificate> cert = QSslCertificate::fromPath(tempssl);

if(cert.size()==1)
{
    ssl_configuration.setCaCertificates(cert);
    m_webSocket.setSslConfiguration(ssl_configuration);
}
else
{
    QString s = "Server certificate not found. Size is " + QString::number(cert.size());
    log(s);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help, whether or not I set QDir dir to QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath().